# gdb: Defining a function with multiple arguments using if...else

Tags: gdb

How can I define a gdb convenience function with optional args? I've tried below, which doesn't work:

```
(gdb) define v
Type commands for definition of "v".
End with a line saying just "end".
>if $argc == 1
 >echo 1
 >else if $argc == 2
 >echo 2
 >else
 >echo neither
 >end
>end
(gdb) v
neither(gdb) v 1
1Undefined command: "else".  Try "help".
(gdb) v 2
1Undefined command: "else".  Try "help".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried below, which doesn't work:

It doesn't work because there is no `else` in the GDB scripting language.

You can work around this with:

```
define v
  if $argc == 1
    echo 1
  end
  if $argc == 2
    echo 2
  end
  if $argc < 1 || 2 < $argc 
    echo neither
  end
end
```

but you'll probably get better results by [deferring to the embedded Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Commands-In-Python.html#index-commands-in-python).

Comment: From what I can see, there is [`else`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html), but no `else if`.